# How to dealloc id<MTLBuffer> metal iOS?

Tags: ios, metal

I'm using
`id<MTLBuffer> vertexBuf = [device newBufferWithLength:count * sizeof(float) options:0];`
 how to dealloc the vertexBuf memory, it increases the memory drastically. In apple's documentation there is no hint to dealloc MTLBuffers.And in my case I can't reuse it again. I have tried  `vertexBuf = nil;` no improvement, and I can't use `[vertexBuf release]` as my project is ARC enabled. Any way to dealloc the memory?

Edit:
I can reuse, but there is an option in OpenGLES2 `glDeleteBuffers` which is useful in many circumstances. So I'm searching similar to that in metal.

Comment: Why can't you reuse the buffer?

Comment: i can reuse, but in there is an option in OpenGLES2 glDeleteBuffers which is useful in many circumstance. So i'm searching  similar to that in metal.

Comment: Try to ask in the Apple dev forums: https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/graphics/metal

Answer (score 1):

Find out who is using vertexBuf. Someone is using it, and holding on to it, or the memory would go away if you set it to nil.

BTW. Release wouldn't help you. ARC does retain/release for you, except it is likely more careful and gets it always right. If you could release it and the memory went away, your app would crash when whoever used vertexBuf releases it as well.

Comment: Consider a state where  you know that no one is holding vertexBuf, in that state we need to dealloc. So how to dealloc?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `[vertexBuf setPurgeableState:MTLPurgeableStateEmpty];`

This is from Apple's documentation:

> If state is MTLPurgeableStateEmpty, the resource is marked as data that can be discarded, because the caller no longer needs the contents of the resource.